# Using group by in AutoMapper

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, automapper

Can we use group by in AutoMapper with C# and Entity Framework? Can you show an example please?

```
CreateMap<x, y>()
            .ForMember(destination => destination.Id)
                options => options.MapFrom(source => source.Id)
            .ForMember(destination => destination.AktifMi,
                options => options.MapFrom(source => true));
```

I will be glad if you apply here

```
var y = _context.XXX.OrderByDescending(i => i.Id);
var ca = _mapper.ProjectTo<x>(y);
```

Comment: Show us the code without AM, with LINQ.

Comment: I added it at the bottom of the thread

Comment: That's not an group by, but yes, that would work. `ProjectTo` is just a `Select` statement.

Comment: I'm sorry but I didn't fully understand your answer.

Comment: can i group in automapper

Comment: yes you can pass a grouping or do group in automapper

Answer (score 0):

you can do whatever you like in automapper.
You just need the correct model to map the source to your destination.

here is a sample snippet.

```html
CreateMap<IGrouping<string, SourceModel>, DestinationModel>()
.ForMember(target => target.Users,
  source => source.MapFrom((src, dest) => {
      return BuilUsers(src);
  }));
  
  
  private IEnumerable<User> BuildUsers(IGrouping<string, SourceModel> source)
  {
      var result = new List<User>();

      foreach (var sourceUser in source)
      {
          result.Add(new User
          {
              UserName = sourceUser.UserName,
          });
      }

      return result;
  }
```

Let me know if you have any further question, Thank you.